# mathkerncmssi source file could not be found

Tags: miktex2.9

I am making use of MiKTex, a flavour of Tex (if i may call it)

On compilation, I get the following error:

> Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully
> contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
> ~\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

Process exited with error(s)

The very same file has been successfully compiled using pdflatex though. Hence, I am concerned about the error. FOr clarity's sake, I am attaching the log file as well.

The contents of the log file are:

> INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: miktex-makemf.exe
> --miktex-disable-maintenance --verbose mathkerncmssi10  FATAL miktex-makemf - The mathkerncmssi source file could not be found.
> FATAL miktex-makemf - The mathkerncmssi source file could not be
> found.  FATAL miktex-makemf - Info:   FATAL miktex-makemf - Source:
> FATAL miktex-makemf - Line: 0

I'm unsure why this error occurs, What am I missing?

Edit (for moderators):
This question was asked, since there were no known questions on this site that provided a solution. To those who downvoted and deleted this query, may I ask why?

This has already been tagged MikTex, and is very much on topic!

Comment: go to the miktex console (user mode) and call the task to recreate the font maps.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by comments.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That looks like an answer to me